# Out of bound error in resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, styles

I have put my shared styles in a single resource dictionary which I include in the application. For example, in a file called `GlobalStyles.xaml` I have the following:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="FrameworkElement">...</Style>
    <Style x:Key="ExtendedStyle" TargetType="FrameworkElement" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">...</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I include this file in the app.xaml as follows:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="GlobalStyles.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

This should work but I am getting the following build error for the ExtendedStyle: `Error: Index was outside the bounds of the array.`. If I remove the `BasedOn` directive I get the same error for `BaseStyle` but none for `ExtendedStyle`. This is really wierd. Can anybody explain this error?

**EDIT:**
The styles are:

```
    <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
    <!-- Background -->
    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="{StaticResource White0ColorBrush}"/>
    <!-- Border -->
    <Setter Property="Control.BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Green1ColorBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <!-- Font -->
    <Setter Property="Control.FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Green0ColorBrush}"/>
    </Style>
```

and

```
<Style x:Key="ExtendedStyle" TargetType="FrameworkElement" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="{StaticResource Green1ColorBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource White0ColorBrush}"/>
</Style>
```

I don't think there is anything special about these two styles. On restarting VS, I am getting the error for another style dependent on `ExtendedStyle`.

**EDIT 2:**
I created a new empty WPF Application project and included the `GlobalStyles.xaml` file in the app.xml. That built fine. Then I added just these lines to the window.xaml and got the same error:

```
    <Grid>
      <Border BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="{StaticResource White0ColorBrush}" Style="{StaticResource ExtendedBaseStyle}">
        <Grid>
           <TextBox x:Name="SearchField" Height="20" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
      </Border>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Tried in a sample, doesn't throw any exception. Did you try restarting VS? Also, can you post XAML for styles as well?

Comment: Wild guess - Maybe try to merge the `GlobalStyles.xaml` with `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>` in app.xaml?

Comment: @sthotakura Restarting VS does not help. I have added the styles as well.

Comment: @Viv Using MergedDictionaries does not help either.

Comment: What is the build action of your GlobalStyles.xaml?

Comment: @Alan I have tried setting build action to `Compile`/`Resource`/`Content` with `Copy` all with the same negative result.

Comment: @341008 Have you tried page? I would at least give that a try... not sure though.

Comment: If you have a simple reproduction of the error now in a sample project you should see about zip'ing the file and attaching it to your question. Maybe if people could download it, they could see what is wrong and if they are having the same problem

Comment: what is `ColoredBaseStyle` in your "Edit 2" is it your `ExtendedStyle`? In a fresh project if I replicate your steps and add the 3 required Brush resources as well(`White0ColorBrush` ...) it works fine.

Comment: @Viv That was a typo. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a bug with VS2012 which I am using. I moved to VS2010 and the problem went away. I have had numerous problems with VS2012 designer. It hangs frequently, throws exceptions, complains about syntax errors when there are none and now this. I will stick to VS2010 for now.